# how to wait until something executes in jquery then to execute another function

Tags: jquery, html, wait

I have a div ("#ImageBingingDiv") which is display none, I fade it in and than i change it's html and add a picutre, after i do that i try to add to the  tag elevateZoom but because the div vas display none somehow it doesn't do what is ment to do, so i think that i have to somehow wait until the image tag is created to add elevateZoom. Any suggestions?

```
$("#ImageBingingDiv").fadeIn(1000);
var widthD = parseInt($("#ImageBingingDiv").css('width')) - 10 + 'px';
var heightD = 0.5625 * (parseInt($("#ImageBingingDiv").css('width')) - 1);
$("#ImageBingingDiv").html('<img id="toZoom" data-zoom-image="./' + id + '" width="' + widthD + '" height="' + heightD + 'px" margin="10px" src="./' + id + '" alt=""/>');
$("#ImageBingingDiv").css('height', heightD + 12 + 'px').css('vertical-align', 'center');

$("#toZoom").elevateZoom({
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
    lensFadeIn: 500,
    lensFadeOut: 500
});
```

Comment: did you tried using settimeoutas mentioned below answer?

Comment: yes i found why it wasnt executing for some reason in chrome doesnt work the zoom in Ie it works...now i am wondering why

Comment: Have you tried more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using jquery `when()`;

or try callback functions.

for ex if u have 2 methods method1 and method2 ..try

```
$.when(method1(), method2()).then(showData);​
```

showdata is executed only when method1(),method2() are finished their execution..

example

```
function showData() {
    alert(something);

}

function method1() {
    //logic
}

function method2() {
  //logic  
}

$.when(method1(), method2()).then(showData);​
```

Comment: whell this with when it blocks all my other jquery animations i cannot enter site and get to the place where i use when

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout, this will make it wait for the element to render.

```
setTimeout(function() {
$("#toZoom").elevateZoom({
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
    lensFadeIn: 500,
    lensFadeOut: 500
});
}, 10);
```